# What function is the equal of the php’s unset to a Varien_Object?

Tags: magento-1.9

```
a.  Unset($param)
b.  uns{$param}()
c.  remove($param)
d.  unregister($param)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$obj->unsData('param');
```

Or

```
$obj->unsParam(); //magic unsetter
```